# APNS certificate expiry date error with MobileFirst Platform 7.0

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

When deploying an APNS certificate in a .wlapp file in MFP 7.0, I'm seeing a null-pointer exception when it validates the end-date, even though it has one. ( `openssl pkcs12 -in apns-certificate-sandbox.p12 | openssl x509  -noout -enddate` returns a valid date in the future).
  It seems others have made this work, so I'm guessing it must be something I am doing wrong...has anyone else resolved similar issues with valid Apple Push Notification Service certs failing to be deployed on MFP
Relevant lines from the log:

```
947: "com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ApplicationService E FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.",
"948: com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.ValidationException: FWLSE3119E: APNS certificate validation failed. See additional messages for details.",
"949: at com.ibm.worklight.admin.util.PushEnvironmentUtil.validateApnsConfiguration(PushEnvironmentUtil.java:232)",
"950: at com.ibm.worklight.admin.util.PushEnvironmentUtil.validatePushConfiguration(PushEnvironmentUtil.java:220)",
    [ ... lots more trace here .. ]
"1030: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException",
"1031:  at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.(ByteArrayInputStream.java:117)",
"1032:  at com.ibm.worklight.admin.util.PushEnvironmentUtil.getCertificateExpiryDate(PushEnvironmentUtil.java:362)",
"1033:  at com.ibm.worklight.admin.util.PushEnvironmentUtil.validateApnsConfiguration(PushEnvironmentUtil.java:230)",
```

Comment: a) Is the apns-certificate-sandbox.p12 certificate placed alongside the application-descriptor.xml in your project. 
b) .wlapp can be unzipped like any archive. Can you verify if the certificate is present in the .wlapp?

Answer (score 1):

Initial hurdle was that the .wlapp file was not being built, so no apns certificate was in the file (it is just in .zip format with a meta directory that should hold the .p12 file).   The underlying issue was that the  tag's password field in application-descriptor.xml wasn't exactly right: it was following the example from "Push Notifications in iOS applications" at https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/push-notifications-native-ios-applications/ :

`<pushSender password="apns-certificate-p12 password"/>`

when it really should just have the password:

`<pushSender password="password"/> </code></pre>`

with the file named either apns-certificate-sandbox.p12 or apns-certificate-production.p12 depending on which server is to be used.

Double dumbass on me for not checking the official docs at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_the_application_descriptor.html , which has it described correctly.

Moral: "When in doubt, RTFM"